# Netsuite Custom formula split string

Tags: netsuite

I have a free-form text custom CRM field that is displayed as time that I would like to convert to a number in order to do basic arithmetic operations. The field is called {actualwork} and displays like this, 3:00. I want to divide it by a decimal number field called {custeven10} and display it in percent.

By using TO_NUMBER and SUBSTR I can convert the text to a number but the number of hours can be higher than a single digit so I don't know how to use the SUBSTR command to split my field. Right now I'm using this command but it only uses the first digit of the string.

```
TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR{actualwork},1,1))/{custevent10}
```

Does anyone know how I could separate the characters before and after the ":" into a two strings? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this formula to transform the text into number and separate the minutes and the hours:

```
(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR({actualwork}, 1, LENGTH({actualwork})-3))+TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR({actualwork}, LENGTH({actualwork})-1,2))/60)/{custevent10}
```